# MDB file of access is not effect on opened program

Tags: php, ms-access

I have a program that using to print ticket for patient. This program use file Autoqueue.mdb as database. There is a table on this database, when you press a print button, it will insert into this table with column TicketNo = lastest Ticket + 1;
For example, the structure of this column will be:

350
351
352
353
354

My aim is: I want to insert into this table by my php code. But, I tried to open this file by Microsoft Access and edit the last line from 354->355. And I press print button, but it still print ticket no. 355 and insert into table with TicketNo=355. It looks like:

353
355
355

I see that when I open this program, there is a file name Autoqueue.ldb. The special thing is when I close this program -> do the same thing -> and restart it, the ticket will be continuted from 366. I think the .ldb file will lock the file, even when I can edit the file but not effect this program until restart.

So sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I know nothing about PHP, but the .ldb file is not related to your issue. It get's created the first time someone (or a program) opens a database. If only one user is using the database, when the database is closed, the ,ldb file goes away. It would be helpful to others if you updated your question and posted the code you are using. It almost sounds like you may be properly updating, but you are not refreshing your local view of the data.